# How to retrieve previous record from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am writing a Custom Query in WordPress database to get the previous record from the posts table.

**Example:**
I have an **ID** of **34975**; after I query the database I should get the **ID** as **34972**, which is the previous record ID.

**SQL**

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM agencies_posts WHERE ID = '34975 ' LIMIT 1", OBJECT );
foreach( $results as $item ){
    $previous_depature_port = $item->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to add `ORDER BY` and use `<` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM agencies_posts 
WHERE ID < 34975 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you want:

```
select *
  from agencies_posts
 where id = (select max(id) from agencies_posts where id < '34975')
```

If the 'current' id is what's known and you just want the one prior.

Comment: This won't select all fields, but rather just find the correct id.

Comment: @sgeddes didn't realize that's what he wanted, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Select everything with an id less than the one you are interested in, and only grab the first one

```
SELECT * 
FROM agencies_posts
WHERE ID < '34975 ' 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"
```